# PivotChart sort by value

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table

How to tell excel to sort pivot chart values by integer value, not alphabetically?

When I use raw time data it sorts correctly:

[image]

But when I use the built in aggregation functionality of Pivotchart for displaying hourly data - sorting goes from sort by value to alphabetical sort:

[image]

Hours 7, 8 and 9 go to the right of the chart.

Values on X axis are duration data form cell that is custom formatted like [h]:mm:ss,000.

Only options that I can see are "sort A -> Z" or "Z -> A"

Answer (score 0):

When you sort, click on "Other sort options". Then you can select the variable for which you want to sort by. Even though it will still say "Ascending (A-Z)" and "Descending (Z-A)", if you select an integer variable then it will sort it numerically.

Comment: Did not work. Seems it treats it as text, not as numbers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but managed to solve it.
It's dependent on the data type you specify.
If you navigate to the column where the data is and change the data type to "whole number", then you will see the axis re-order to how you need/expect it.